# Finding the $2\times 2$ determinant using row operations and upper triangular matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, determinant

> Calculate $\begin{vmatrix}
> 3 &-5 \\ 
>  2&6 
> \end{vmatrix}$.

I want to use row operations, and so what I did first was interchange the rows, which multiplies the determinant by $-1$. Then I wanted the $2$ to be a leading one, so I multiplied the first row by $\frac{1}{2}$, which multiplies the determinant by $\frac{1}{2}$. Then I eliminate the $3$ in the second row. I get the resulting determinant:

$-\frac{1}{2}\begin{vmatrix}
1&3 \\ 
 0&-14 
\end{vmatrix}$

So then the determinant is $7$. However, I know this is wrong. Could someone please tell me what I did wrong to get an incorrect determinant?

Comment: That $\frac{1}{2}$ should be a $2$.

Comment: @GuidoA. May I ask why that is?

Comment: Of course, sorry for the lack of an explanation. If you multiply a row by $\frac{1}{2}$, you are calculating $\frac{1}{2}$ of the determinant, as you correctly stated. So to get the actual value of the determinant, you should 'fix' this offset by multiplying by 2.

Comment: @GuidoA. I see! Thank you for a very clear explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to know what types of operations change the determinant. Replacing a row after you've scaled it will scale the determinant. So you should replace a row you didn't scale. For example:$$\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
3&-5\\
2&6
\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}
0&-14\\
2&6
\end{bmatrix}}_{R_1-\frac{3}{2}R_2\implies R_1}$$
Which has determinant $28.$

Now, you swapped two rows, so you are right to change the sign. But when you multiplied by $\frac{1}{2}$ you then need to **multiply** by 2 to get the correct determinant in the end.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to make a clear explanation. :)

Comment: No trouble! I think the best thing to do, in the future, is to play with the identity matrix. It's easy to see the consequences of your operations that way. For example, you can see that replacing a row without scaling it preserves the determinant: 

$$\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0&1
\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}
1&5\\
0&1
\end{bmatrix}}_{R_1+5R_2\implies R_1}$$

Answer (score 2):

You took the $2$ out by taking $1/2$ out, i.e., you actually used $(2a) = 1/2*a$.

Answer (score 2):

Along those lines, what you should have done was:\begin{align}\begin{vmatrix}3&-5\\2&6\end{vmatrix}&=-\begin{vmatrix}2&6\\3&-5\end{vmatrix}\\&=-2\begin{vmatrix}1&3\\3&-5\end{vmatrix}\\&=-2\begin{vmatrix}1&3\\0&-14\end{vmatrix}\\&=28.\end{align}